# Facing 302 redirect in laravel 5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am POST data from ajax to controller/method but facing 302 redirect when ajax is hitting the method but still it show 302 error.. if i hit the ajax method direct from url and return anything it works but if i call ajax() function using ajax it redirects to the login view. why?

controller

```
public function ajax(Request $request){ 
return 1;}
```

route

```
Route::group(array('module'=>'Guest','namespace' => 
'App\Modules\Guest\Controllers'), function() {

Route::post('ajax','GuestController@ajax')->name('ajax');
}
```

script:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
        $(document).ready(function(){

        // Load more data
        $('.load-more').click(function(){
            var row = Number($('#row').val());
            var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
            var rowperpage = 3;
            row = row + rowperpage;

            if(row <= allcount){
                $("#row").val(row);

                $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('GuestController/ajax')}}",
                type: 'post',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: {row:row},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
 });

            }else{

                console.log('if is not working');
            }

        });

        });
```

it should hit the ajax() method.

Comment: Try it in Postman and see what that says.

Comment: @Deckerz i update the question

Comment: If its redirecting it means your session isn't working through the ajax call. Maybe try using axios which is bundled in Laravel to make this call. This way we can see if its a jQuery specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the name of your route here: `->name('ajax');` and can call that route by using the **route()** function and passing the name through.

Change your ajax url to use the route name

Example : `url: "{{ route('ajax') }}",`

also add error function to your ajax script like success function:

`error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Some Error');
    }`

your ajax function should return JSON so your function should look like this below:

`public function ajax(Request $request){ 
   return response()->json(1);
}`

Comment: still same error but it work with `get` type on `post` type it redirects me to the login view even not using any middleware

Comment: worked after adding this line
  `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: so your template doesn't have a csrf-token field and because of that it was getting redirected. I hope now you can close this topic.

Comment: so your template doesn't have a csrf-token field and because of that it was getting redirected. I hope now you can close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Add "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest". This is particularly for security as it can prevent CSRF attacks because this header cannot be added to the AJAX request cross domain without the consent of the server via CORS.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 beforeSend: function(request) {
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
 }
});
```